# Select2 - Load data dynamically

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I'm using the **select2** plugin. I'm trying to make the e3 "load" data from array regions based on the second select box. This is my code:

```
var regions = [{"first":["City1", "City2"],"second":["City3", "City4"]}];
$('#e2').select2().on('change', function() {
    $.each(regions[($("#e2").val())], function(key,value) {
        $("#e3").append("<option value='"+value+"'>"+value+"</option>");
    });
}).trigger('change');
```

EDIT: The error I get, every time I change the `#e2`'s value is: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks! :)

EDIT2:

```
$('#e2').select2().on('change', function() {
    $.each(region[$("#e2").select2("val")], function(key,value) {
        alert(region[$("#e2").select2("val")]);
        $("#e3").append("<option value='"+value+"'>"+value+"</option>");
    });
}).trigger('change');
```

This was suggested... It still gives the previous error (Uncaught TypeError). The alert however returns: undefined

Answer (score 0):

This: `$("#e2").val()` should change to this: `$("#e2").select2("val")`

Comment: what does it return in console if you alert the value?

Comment: so what does the alert say? does it get a number or text?

Comment: sorry, forgot to include that - it says undefined

Comment: what does `alert($("#e2").select2("val");` say? without region[...]

Comment: it returns the value as it should

Comment: the value is text - for example "first" or "second" (without quotation marks), from the array
(I have a script that builds the #e2 from the same array)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27187/discussion-between-pangi-and-jake-zeitz)